# Why are my types not working out? (Use of type 'a pred = 'a -> bool)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I have been stuck on this question for a while. I've been editing and reviewing and changing the types for a while but I can't get the type checker to accept what I am doing, probably because I don't fully understand the error/where I am going wrong on this. I am working with the type:

```ml
type 'a pred = 'a -> bool
```

I believe this means I can use `'a pred` as a shortcut to mean `'a -> bool`, so an int going to result in a bool in my case, but I don't fully get how to implement it because I can't find many examples on this online which I  have checked for.

My latest version is below, but I am getting a few errors from the checker, including Error: operator and operand do not agree. Would someone be able to explain where my error is, and why?

Edit: I now think there is a mismatch between this function and the rest of the code. The rest of the code requires it to be an 'a, polymorphic, while here I am assuming it is an int. However, I'm not sure how to do this function (check if odd) while keeping it a polymorphic type.

```
 fun isOdd (p : int) : bool  = 
    case p 
      of 1 => true
      | 0 => false
      | _ => isOdd (p - 2)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. First you start off talking about `type 'a pred = 'a -> bool`; then you show a code snippet that doesn't refer to `pred` at all, and from the surrounding text, it sounds like you recognize that the issue with that code snippet has nothing to do with `pred`. Could you figure out what your actual question is, and then ask that question? Feel free to delete any parts of your question that aren't actually part of your question. :-)

Comment: The problem lies where you're using this. My hunch is that you have `fun f x = ... isOdd x ...`, but you should have `fun f p x = ... p x ...`, and pass `isOdd` to that function, but please read about the [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> I believe this means I can use `'a pred` as a shortcut to mean `'a -> bool`

That is correct.

In the case of your `isOdd` predicate, it is an `int pred`:

```
> val isOdd = fn : int -> bool
- isOdd : int pred;
> val it = fn : int -> bool
```

Perhaps your misconception lies in the fact that in spite of expressing `: int pred`, the result in the REPL is still described as `int -> bool`? This is because we have only defined a type alias, and those tend reduce to their non-aliased form in SML.

Or perhaps your misconception lies in the `'a` reducing to some concrete value? You can operate with `'a pred` by not referring to concrete values of `'a`. For example, if you want to filter an `'a list` for only values that are true for a given `'a pred`, then the standard function `List.filter` will have the type:

```
- List.filter : 'a pred -> 'a list -> 'a list;
> val 'a it = fn : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

> I'm not sure how to do this function (check if odd) while keeping it a polymorphic type.

I'm not sure, either.

Oddness is a property of integers, not arbitrary types `'a`.

You would need to extend the meaning of "odd" to any type first. Then you would need some kind of overloading, since the oddness of every type presumably isn't determined by the same mechanism. I'm pretty sure this is a side-track caused by one or two confusions.

Comment: Thank you! I think I was misunderstanding what I had to do a large amount. Sorry I asked a question that was not easy to answer